# Creating one instance with Unity and use it everywhere

Tags: c#, unity-container

Hi I am using unity as my IoC framework and I have a case where I need to use the same instance of an object in my entire application , bassicly creating a singleton.

Let's say I have this configuration:

```
container.RegisterType<IValidationService, ValidationService>();
```

How would I go about in telling unity to create only one instance of the ValidationService and use it everywhere in my app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()` like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IValidationService, ValidationService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx